# Linux kernel filesystem multithreading

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems

Do file systems in linux operate in multithread mode?
I have a small fs written using wrapfs, wanted to know if read operations that the fs executes ("wrapfs_read"), happen in multithread mode.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Filesystem(FS) in linux operates in multi-threaded mode. FS handles all the read/write request in concurrent fashion. E.g. you open many applications all those will issues read/writes in parallel will be handled by FS concurrently. Every call comes to FS via [VFS layer](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/usenix01/full_papers/kroeger/kroeger_html/node8.html) in kernel.
And being in the kernel space one always has to keep concurrency in mind while programming as linux kernel itself is multi-threaded.

Answer (score 1):

Yes File Systems in Linux operate in Multi-threading mode. 
Please go through http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html
to understand file control, especially handling threads with respect to file read/writes.